# use php larval helper function in jQuery blade file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

**I have created function in laravel helper function to convert base currency to IP currency it is working when page get reload but in product attribute when we select option price get changed how can I use laravel helper function in jQuery.**

```
// This function is to change the base price to ip currency price.
function convertBaseCurrencyToIp($base_price){
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    $arr_ip = geoip()->getLocation($ipaddress);
    $base_currency = 'INR';
    $currency_of_ip = $arr_ip->currency;
    $currency_conversion = Currency::convert()->from($base_currency)->to($currency_of_ip)->amount($base_price)->round(2)->get();

    return $currency_conversion;
}
```

**and this is jQuery code**

```
$(document).on("click",".clear-attributes",function (){
        $(".checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
        $("#price").text(site_currency_symbol + parseFloat($("#price").data("main-price")).toFixed(2));

        let old_image = $("#product-image").val();
        $(".attribute_img").attr("src",old_image);

        showAndHideClearButton($(".checkbox:checked").length);
    })

    $(document).on("click",".checkbox",function (){
        showAndHideClearButton($(".checkbox:checked").length);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either pass it as a value to your view.

```php
$conversion = convertBaseCurrencyToIp($base_price)

return view('your-view', ['conversion' => $conversion]);
```

and then reference that value in your blade file.

```xml
<script>
const conversion = '{{ $conversion }}';
...
</script>
```

But if you need something more dynamic (javascript reacting to something on your page and then showing a value) then you probably need to create an endpoint and make a request to it.

```
Route::get('conversion-endpoint', ConversionController::class);
```

```php
class ConversionController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => [
                'value' => convertBaseCurrencyToIp($request->base_price),
            ]
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

```js
// js
$(document).on("click",".clear-attributes",function (){
    ...
    $.ajax('/conversion-endpoint').done(function (data) {
        const converted = data.value; // or data.data.value, I can't remember if jquery adds a wrapper or not
        ....
    })
```